# fill Nas with other column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I have some NAs and would like to fill them with values in another column in the same row.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"column A": ["Atlanta", "Atlanta", "New York", "",""], 
                   "column B": ["AT", "AT", "NY", "1", ""]})
```

| columnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| Atlanta | AT |
| Atlanta | AT |
| Newyork | NY |
|  | 1 |
|  |  |

Expected output:

| columnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| Atlanta | AT |
| Atlanta | AT |
| Newyork | NY |
| 1 | 1 |
|  |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Simply Use the `fillna` with the Column Name like this:

```
df['column A'].fillna(df['column B'])
```